# Create test instance in Junit 5 with factory method (no dynamic test)

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

Using JUnit 4, one could take control over test instance lifecycle using runners. For instance, I used to implement method `createTest()` of `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` to have a fine-tuned instance creation (in my case, use Weld to retrieve a CDI-ready instance).

With JUnit 5, [extensions](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) are supposed to replace runners and rules. Yet, I cannot find a way to hook into test instance creation the way I could with JUnit 4.

Is there a way to tell JUnit Jupiter how to create my test instance (for example, using Weld container) without using dynamic tests?

Here is what I do now in JUnit 4, and want to be able to do in Jupiter:

```java
public class ContainerRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    private WeldContainer container;

    ...

    @Override
    public Object createTest() {
        return container.select(this.getTestClass().getJavaClass()).get();
    }
}
```

And later:

```java
@RunWith(ContainerRunner.class)
@Singleton
public class ContainedTest {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;  // this works

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: This is currently not possible. There is already an open issue about this: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/672. However it is not slated for the next release (5.1).

Comment: Thanks @eee, I subscribed to the issue. In the mean time, I stick to old good JUnit 4.

Comment: If you want to use weld together with junit5 you might have a look at: https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit#junit5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By now, it's probably best to use one of the two [Weld JUnit 5 Extensions](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit/blob/master/junit5/README.md).

But to answer your question directly, you can (3 years later) write an extension that implements `TestInstanceFactory`, i.e.:

```java
class ContainerExtension implements TestInstanceFactory {
    private WeldContainer container;

    @Override public Object createTestInstance(TestInstanceFactoryContext factoryContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws TestInstantiationException {
        return container.select(this.getTestClass().getJavaClass()).get();
    }
}
```

Then your test uses `@ExtendWith(ContainerExtension.class)` instead of `@RunWith(ContainerRunner.class)`.